# SVN Repository with Authz

Tags: svn

**What I need:**

I need to have an account for developers (read and write) and another one (user3) read only (for updating).

**Configuration of my repository**

files are in:

1. `/home/svnrepos/repo1/`
2. `/home/svnrepos/repo2/`

my apache .conf file: (`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/svn.conf`)

```
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /svn/repo1>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /home/svnrepos/repo1
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Repo One"
  AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/subversion/authz
  Require valid-user
</Location>
...
```

and authz file: `/etc/subversion/authz`

```
[repo1:/]
* =
user1 = rw
user2 = rw

[repo1:/trunk]
user1 = rw
user2 = rw
user3 = r

[repo2:/]
* =
user1 = rw
user2 = rw
```

When I try to visit `https://example.com/svn/repo1`: (without ask username and password)

[image: svn from browser]

but if I go to https://example.com/svn/repo1/foo it works (ask me username and password).

Why I can't see the root of this repository?

I've tried to follow this [guide](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/svn-subversion-access-control-with-apache-and-mod-authz-svn/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was another repository called like "repo1OLD". I don't know why, but removing it solves the issue.